# How to get setState to update the interface when using an array of Widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code is inside setState:

```
setState(){
    holes[index - 1] = Hole(
      heightt: 240,
      widthh: 80,
      index: index,
      marbles: 0,
      updateList: updateList);
  }
```

The array stores a bunch of Hole widgets, which are created in another class. In the build method, I call on the array to build the Hole widgets onto the screen;

```
Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
       children: [holes[13], holes[1]]),)
```

The Hole widget (located in another class) stores a button that calls the method that contains setState (in the main class), which then changes the marbles variable. However, the change in the number of marbles is not reflected on screen.

Comment: You can't manipulate other widgets with `setState()` like that. You need a state management library for that. Check out https://pub.dev/packages/provider it should be the simplest in order to start.

Comment: Actually, I'm finding RiverPod easier to describe, and of course it's more powerful than Provider.